# HDD visible in BIOS and WD Dashboard, but not in Win10 Disk Manager

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, bios, raid

I have two WD Blue and two WD Red drives. All were working perfectly fine on my Win10 PC up until I have reinstalled the system. Now I only see two WD Red drives.

When I connect these (Blue) drives through external USB to SATA interface they’re working fine.

1. I can see the drives in BIOS.
2. I can see the drives in WD Dashboard in Windows (screenshot below).
3. I don’t see these Blue drives in Windows Disk Management.

Any ideas what could be the problem and how to solve/troubleshoot it?

[image]

Comment: You installed the appropriate RAID drivers? Based on your screenshot your two WD Blue disks were in a RAID.

Comment: What @Ramhound said. 1)Are there any unknown devices in DevMan (Device Manager)? 2)Can you tell us your PC and/or RAID model? 3)Reply with DevMan `IDE/ATA/ATAPI controllers` & `Storage controllers`

Comment: There was no RAID configuration, it was two separate disk visible in Windows. 1) There is an unknown "Disk 1" In disk manager, but with smaller size. 2) It's a PC with Asus Z170 PRO GAMING motherboard. 3) This question I don't understand.
In Drive Man it asks me whether I want to initialize the disk with MBR or LPT, but I don't want to risk I will loose the data on these disks. Especially that I see and can use all the data when connect them through external SATA-USB interface.

Comment: Sounds like you CAN see the drives in Disk Management then, but just not seeing the partitions expected. Have you *been using* them with external adapter? It's well known that some adapter "group" logical sectors (8 to 1) to emulate a logical sector size of 4096 bytes.

Comment: @WojtusJ - your screenshot tells a different story. Your screenshot clearly indicates the WD Blue disks were in a RAID. “Not supported on RAID devices” is another clue they were in a RAID

Comment: Well, thanks for suggestions. I just copied the data to another disk and formatted two Blue ones, now it works fine. I have no idea what was it. When I tried to initialize uninitialized partition I got CRC error. Topic can be closed.